# Hide seconds in Babel's medium/long formats

Tags: python, python-babel

We're using Babel to format datetime objects nicely according to the user's locale. In many cases we show data which does not contain non-zero seconds ever (such as real-life event start times).

While it'd be easy with a custom format string to get rid of the seconds, there doesn't appear any easy way to do so when using the locale-provided ones like *'medium'* or *'short'*.

Is there any clean way to modify these strings besides hooking into babel's internals to modify the format string returned from the locale data?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by subclassing `Locale` and overriding the formatting properties?

```
class MyLocale(babel.Locale):
    @property
    def time_formats(self):
        formats = super(MyLocale, self).time_formats
        for k, v in formats.items():
            v.format = v.format.replace(':%(ss)s', '')
        return formats

>> l = MyLocale('en')
>> l.time_formats['medium'].apply(datetime.datetime.now(), l)
u'9:05 AM'
```